# How to increase number in middle whole number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have numbers like this :

```
4010301001

40103001001
```

I want to increase the number in middle whole number like example :

```
4010302001

40103002001
```

And if is there a role for increase the numbers with any place of whole number.

Comment: Why do you need to do this, assuming your question is not a homework assignment?

Comment: Please explain the logic.  How do you determine which digit gets incremented?  What happens when it is 9?

Comment: What do you mean by increase the "middle" number; there's 10 characters in your number, so there's 6 number "in the middle", or the exact middle with between the 5 and 6th digits. This makes no sense.

Comment: I want to do this for accounting tree for ledger account.

Comment: After reach to 9 will be 10 and the number will be : Before edit :4010301001 after edit :4010310001

Comment: "*After reach to 9 will be 10 and the number will be*" But there's no 9's in the number `4010301001`. You're not making sense.

Comment: Aren't you just adding 1000?

Comment: No i did not reach to 1000 the max will be 15 that's all

Comment: Someone solve the issue I can handle the code : select concat( left(col, len(col) - 3) + 1, right(col, 3))

Comment: If Gordon's answer *does* answer the question, @mandarinsoftware (That was a very good guess if so), then mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like:

```
select concat( left(col, len(col) - 3) + 1, right(col, 3))
```